# How to Expose a Hierarchy in Groups T-SQL

Tags: t-sql

I'm trying to figure out a way to handle this hierarchy, but I'm not sure exactly how to. For sake of simplicity, I've made this example data:

```
CREATE TABLE #EXAMPLE (
    ID INT
    , PARENT_ID INT
    , [PATH] VARCHAR(1000)
    , [TYPE] VARCHAR(10)
    );

INSERT INTO #EXAMPLE ([ID], PARENT_ID, [PATH], [TYPE]) VALUES 
     (63812, 0, '/Home', 'Folder')
    ,(55225, 63812, '/Home/User1', 'Folder')
    ,(92901, 63812, '/Home/User2', 'Folder')
    ,(40353, 63812, '/Home/User3', 'Folder')
    ,(96959, 55225, '/Home/User1/Item1', 'File')
    ,(97231, 55225, '/Home/User1/Item2', 'File')
    ,(53339, 92901, '/Home/User2/Item1', 'File')
    ,(58034, 92901, '/Home/User2/Music', 'Folder')
    ,(65023, 58034, '/Home/User2/Music/Item1', 'File')
    ,(72657, 58034, '/Home/User2/Music/Item2', 'File')
    ,(19406, 58034, '/Home/User2/Music/Item3', 'File')
    ,(56515, 58034, '/Home/User2/Music/Item4', 'File')
    ,(68394, 58034, '/Home/User2/Music/Item5', 'File')
    ,(42813, 92901, '/Home/User2/Movies', 'Folder')
    ,(32781, 42813, '/Home/User2/Movies/Item1', 'File')
    ,(96579, 40353, '/Home/User3/Scripts', 'Folder')    
    ,(36300, 96579, '/Home/User3/Scripts/Item1', 'File')
    ,(59930, 96579, '/Home/User3/Scripts/SQL', 'Folder')
    ,(83700, 59930, '/Home/User3/Scripts/SQL/Item1', 'File')
    ,(66753, 59930, '/Home/User3/Scripts/SQL/Item2', 'File')
    ,(34377, 96579, '/Home/User3/Scripts/Other', 'Folder')
    ,(20666, 34377, '/Home/User3/Scripts/Other/Item1', 'File')
    ,(23786, 34377, '/Home/User3/Scripts/Other/Item2', 'File')
    ,(87107, 34377, '/Home/User3/Scripts/Other/Item3', 'File')
    ,(29557, 34377, '/Home/User3/Scripts/Other/Item4', 'File')


SELECT E.*
FROM #EXAMPLE AS E

DROP TABLE #EXAMPLE
```

It's a file path hierarchy, and what I want to do is ultimately make a report that will show, for instance, that there are 16 files under "/Home", and then you could drill-down to the next hierarchy level and see that "/Home/User1" has 2 files, "/Home/User2" has 7 files, and so forth.

I may be overthinking this... but to do so, I believe I have to show elements that are shared in common among the different file paths. At first, I tried something like this (after the table creation statement):

```
;WITH E_CTE AS (
    SELECT E.ID, E.PARENT_ID, E.[PATH], E.[TYPE], [LVL] = 0--, [COMMON_ROOT] = SUBSTRING(E.[PATH], 0, 0)
    FROM #EXAMPLE AS E
    WHERE E.ID = 63812
    UNION ALL
    SELECT EXM.ID, EXM.PARENT_ID, EXM.[PATH], EXM.[TYPE], CTE.LVL + 1--, SUBSTRING(EXM.[PATH], 0, CTE.LVL)
    FROM E_CTE AS CTE
        INNER JOIN #EXAMPLE AS EXM
            ON CTE.ID = EXM.PARENT_ID
    )


SELECT E.PARENT_ID, [PARENT_PATH] = ISNULL(EXM.[PATH], ''), E.ID, E.[PATH], E.[TYPE], E.LVL
FROM E_CTE AS E
    LEFT JOIN #EXAMPLE AS EXM
        ON E.PARENT_ID = EXM.ID
ORDER BY E.LVL, E.[PATH]

DROP TABLE #EXAMPLE
```

This gives me a dataset where I can see the immediate parent of a given record, but I can't see each parent element broken down. A hierarchy of PARENT_PATH and PATH makes it look like there are 9 parent groups, when I want it to show that there is one group at the top, "/Home", three groups at the second level, "/Home/User1", "/Home/User2", and "/Home/User3", and so forth. What I've arrived at is that I need a data set something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #EXAMPLE (
    ID INT
    , PARENT_ID INT
    , LEVEL_0 VARCHAR(1000)
    , LEVEL_1 VARCHAR(1000)
    , LEVEL_2 VARCHAR(1000)
    , LEVEL_3 VARCHAR(1000)
    , LEVEL_4 VARCHAR(1000)
    , [PATH] VARCHAR(1000)
    , [TYPE] VARCHAR(10)
    );

INSERT INTO #EXAMPLE ([ID], PARENT_ID, LEVEL_0, LEVEL_1, LEVEL_2, LEVEL_3, LEVEL_4,  [PATH], [TYPE]) VALUES 

(63812, 0,      '/Home',    NULL,           NULL,                   NULL,                           NULL,                               '/Home',                            'Folder')
,(55225, 63812, '/Home',    '/Home/User1',  NULL,                   NULL,                           NULL,                               '/Home/User1',                      'Folder')
,(92901, 63812, '/Home',    '/Home/User2',  NULL,                   NULL,                           NULL,                               '/Home/User2',                      'Folder')
,(40353, 63812, '/Home',    '/Home/User3',  NULL,                   NULL,                           NULL,                               '/Home/User3',                      'Folder')
,(96959, 55225, '/Home',    '/Home/User1',  '/Home/User1/Item1',    NULL,                           NULL,                               '/Home/User1/Item1',                'File')
,(97231, 55225, '/Home',    '/Home/User1',  '/Home/User1/Item2',    NULL,                           NULL,                               '/Home/User1/Item2',                'File')
,(53339, 92901, '/Home',    '/Home/User2',  '/Home/User2/Item1',    NULL,                           NULL,                               '/Home/User2/Item1',                'File')
,(58034, 92901, '/Home',    '/Home/User2',  '/Home/User2/Music',    NULL,                           NULL,                               '/Home/User2/Music',                'Folder')
,(65023, 58034, '/Home',    '/Home/User2',  '/Home/User2/Music',    '/Home/User2/Music/Item1',      NULL,                               '/Home/User2/Music/Item1',          'File')
,(72657, 58034, '/Home',    '/Home/User2',  '/Home/User2/Music',    '/Home/User2/Music/Item2',      NULL,                               '/Home/User2/Music/Item2',          'File')
,(19406, 58034, '/Home',    '/Home/User2',  '/Home/User2/Music',    '/Home/User2/Music/Item3',      NULL,                               '/Home/User2/Music/Item3',          'File')
,(56515, 58034, '/Home',    '/Home/User2',  '/Home/User2/Music',    '/Home/User2/Music/Item4',      NULL,                               '/Home/User2/Music/Item4',          'File')
,(68394, 58034, '/Home',    '/Home/User2',  '/Home/User2/Music',    '/Home/User2/Music/Item5',      NULL,                               '/Home/User2/Music/Item5',          'File')
,(42813, 92901, '/Home',    '/Home/User2',  '/Home/User2/Movies',   NULL,                           NULL,                               '/Home/User2/Movies',               'Folder')
,(32781, 42813, '/Home',    '/Home/User2',  '/Home/User2/Movies',   '/Home/User2/Movies/Item1',     NULL,                               '/Home/User2/Movies/Item1',         'File')
,(96579, 40353, '/Home',    '/Home/User3',  '/Home/User3/Scripts',  NULL,                           NULL,                               '/Home/User3/Scripts',              'Folder')
,(36300, 96579, '/Home',    '/Home/User3',  '/Home/User3/Scripts',  '/Home/User3/Scripts/Item1',    NULL,                               '/Home/User3/Scripts/Item1',        'File')
,(59930, 96579, '/Home',    '/Home/User3',  '/Home/User3/Scripts',  '/Home/User3/Scripts/SQL',      NULL,                               '/Home/User3/Scripts/SQL',          'Folder')
,(83700, 59930, '/Home',    '/Home/User3',  '/Home/User3/Scripts',  '/Home/User3/Scripts/SQL',      '/Home/User3/Scripts/SQL/Item1',    '/Home/User3/Scripts/SQL/Item1',    'File')
,(66753, 59930, '/Home',    '/Home/User3',  '/Home/User3/Scripts',  '/Home/User3/Scripts/SQL',      '/Home/User3/Scripts/SQL/Item2',    '/Home/User3/Scripts/SQL/Item2',    'File')
,(34377, 96579, '/Home',    '/Home/User3',  '/Home/User3/Scripts',  '/Home/User3/Scripts/Other',    NULL,                               '/Home/User3/Scripts/Other',        'Folder')
,(20666, 34377, '/Home',    '/Home/User3',  '/Home/User3/Scripts',  '/Home/User3/Scripts/Other',    '/Home/User3/Scripts/Other/Item1',  '/Home/User3/Scripts/Other/Item1',  'File')
,(23786, 34377, '/Home',    '/Home/User3',  '/Home/User3/Scripts',  '/Home/User3/Scripts/Other',    '/Home/User3/Scripts/Other/Item2',  '/Home/User3/Scripts/Other/Item2',  'File')
,(87107, 34377, '/Home',    '/Home/User3',  '/Home/User3/Scripts',  '/Home/User3/Scripts/Other',    '/Home/User3/Scripts/Other/Item3',  '/Home/User3/Scripts/Other/Item3',  'File')
,(29557, 34377, '/Home',    '/Home/User3',  '/Home/User3/Scripts',  '/Home/User3/Scripts/Other',    '/Home/User3/Scripts/Other/Item4',  '/Home/User3/Scripts/Other/Item4',  'File')

SELECT * FROM #EXAMPLE

DROP TABLE #EXAMPLE
```

This dataset shows me each row-level item (folder or file), the path, but then the entire "shared path" at each level of the hierarchy. My question is, how do I get from my first dataset to this dataset, using T-SQL? (That is, how do I get to that dynamically?) It would involve a dynamic number of columns depending on how many levels there are (in the production data there's more like seven or eight levels).

A secondary question is this: is there an alternative way to arrange/tabulate/organize this data such that in a reporting tool like SSRS or Tableau, I could drill down from the top level down to the bottom level in the manner I've described?

Thanks to anyone who takes the time to look at this question.

Comment: Is there an upper limit on the number of levels? Life might be easier if you simply split all of the levels apart so that you're just dealing with parent/child relations, e.g. `'User2'` is the parent of (an instance of) `'Movies'` without all of the extra bits in the strings. You can always use a recursive CTE, perhaps in a `view`, to assemble the partial or complete paths (and counts) when needed. Aside: If you use the statement terminator (`;`) consistently you won't need oddities like `;with`.

Comment: There isn't a hard and fast upper limit, but practically speaking I can't really see it being more than 15 or so. I think I get what you're saying but my production data set starts with the full path, so would that still work?

Comment: (And yes, you're right about the statement terminator, thank you!)

Comment: I made some progress when I found this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CHbqIsw5X30&list=PLNIs-AWhQzcmEFHyxCRwA_gb29WOz5SJU&index=25. However, it only seems to display the hierarchy I'm wanting to see, but isn't actually grouping things together how I need them to be in order to calculate, say, how many descendent child files there are per folder. I have since been trying to split the path by '/' so that for each item it shows all the "ancestor components" of that item, but I'm not quite there yet... Any help would still be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through some investigation I figured out what I needed, which wasn't what I asked for (didn't have the vocabulary to know what exactly to ask for starting off). After looking at the link from Wise Owl (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CHbqIsw5X30&list=PLNIs-AWhQzcmEFHyxCRwA_gb29WOz5SJU&index=28) I also referenced *T-SQL Querying* by Itzik Ben-Gan (2015) pp. 778-786 and came up with this nested set solution:

```
DECLARE @root AS INT = 63812;

CREATE TABLE #EXAMPLE (
    ID INT
    , PARENT_ID INT
    , [PATH] VARCHAR(1000)
    , [TYPE] VARCHAR(10)
    );

INSERT INTO #EXAMPLE ([ID], PARENT_ID, [PATH], [TYPE]) VALUES 
     (63812, 0, '/Home', 'Folder')
    ,(55225, 63812, '/Home/User1', 'Folder')
    ,(92901, 63812, '/Home/User2', 'Folder')
    ,(40353, 63812, '/Home/User3', 'Folder')
    ,(96959, 55225, '/Home/User1/Item1', 'File')
    ,(97231, 55225, '/Home/User1/Item2', 'File')
    ,(53339, 92901, '/Home/User2/Item1', 'File')
    ,(58034, 92901, '/Home/User2/Music', 'Folder')
    ,(65023, 58034, '/Home/User2/Music/Item1', 'File')
    ,(72657, 58034, '/Home/User2/Music/Item2', 'File')
    ,(19406, 58034, '/Home/User2/Music/Item3', 'File')
    ,(56515, 58034, '/Home/User2/Music/Item4', 'File')
    ,(68394, 58034, '/Home/User2/Music/Item5', 'File')
    ,(42813, 92901, '/Home/User2/Movies', 'Folder')
    ,(32781, 42813, '/Home/User2/Movies/Item1', 'File')
    ,(96579, 40353, '/Home/User3/Scripts', 'Folder')    
    ,(36300, 96579, '/Home/User3/Scripts/Item1', 'File')
    ,(59930, 96579, '/Home/User3/Scripts/SQL', 'Folder')
    ,(83700, 59930, '/Home/User3/Scripts/SQL/Item1', 'File')
    ,(66753, 59930, '/Home/User3/Scripts/SQL/Item2', 'File')
    ,(34377, 96579, '/Home/User3/Scripts/Other', 'Folder')
    ,(20666, 34377, '/Home/User3/Scripts/Other/Item1', 'File')
    ,(23786, 34377, '/Home/User3/Scripts/Other/Item2', 'File')
    ,(87107, 34377, '/Home/User3/Scripts/Other/Item3', 'File')
    ,(29557, 34377, '/Home/User3/Scripts/Other/Item4', 'File');


WITH TwoNums AS (
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(1), (2)) AS D(n)
    )
, SortPath AS (
    SELECT EXM.ID, EXM.[PATH], EXM.[TYPE], TN.n, [LVL] = 0, [SORT_PATH] = CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), CONVERT(BINARY(4), TN.n))
    FROM #EXAMPLE AS EXM
        CROSS JOIN TwoNums AS TN
    WHERE EXM.ID = @root

    UNION ALL

    SELECT E.ID, E.[PATH], E.[TYPE], TNS.n, SP.LVL + 1, SP.SORT_PATH + CONVERT(BINARY(4), (-1 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY E.PARENT_ID
        ORDER BY E.[PATH])) / 2 * 2 + TNS.n)
    FROM SortPath AS SP
        INNER JOIN #EXAMPLE AS E
            ON SP.n = 1
            AND E.PARENT_ID = SP.ID
        CROSS JOIN TwoNums AS TNS
    )
, Sort AS (
    SELECT SP.ID, SP.[PATH], SP.[TYPE], [SortVal] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SP.SORT_PATH)
    FROM SortPath AS SP
    )
, NestedSets AS (
    SELECT SRT.ID, SRT.[PATH], SRT.[TYPE], [LFT] = MIN(SRT.SortVal), [RGT] = MAX(SRT.SortVal)
    FROM Sort AS SRT
    GROUP BY SRT.ID, SRT.[PATH], SRT.[TYPE]
    )


SELECT NS.*, EXM.PARENT_ID
INTO #StructureNS
FROM NestedSets AS NS
    INNER JOIN #EXAMPLE AS EXM 
        ON NS.ID = EXM.ID;


SELECT NS.PARENT_ID, NS.ID, NS.[PATH], NS.[TYPE]
    , [CNT_FILES] = 
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CHLD.ID)
    FROM #StructureNS AS PRNT
        INNER JOIN #StructureNS AS CHLD
            ON CHLD.LFT BETWEEN PRNT.LFT AND PRNT.RGT
    WHERE CHLD.RGT - CHLD.LFT = 1
        AND PRNT.[TYPE] = 'Folder'
        AND CHLD.[TYPE] = 'File'
        AND NS.ID = PRNT.ID
    )
FROM #StructureNS AS NS

DROP TABLE #EXAMPLE, #StructureNS
```

What I was going after was how do perform various aggregations (such as a count of files) at each level of a given recursive hierarchy. The T-SQL code does that nicely, though it seems like it would be possible with SSRS and a "Recursive" argument. Either way, the SSRS Recursive advanced setting allows me to display the data in the manner I was looking for, which was to drill down from the root out through all the nodes.